# Create gem locally and skip rake install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm creating a ruby gem using Bundler for a simple rackup app (not Rails). It's a real pain to run rake install and then restart the webserver everytime. For most part it's ok because I test everything using rspec but not design. My gem contains a whole lot of design and everytime I update my gem I have to go threw the same procedure.

Is it possible to build gems locally without having to run `rake install` and then restart my rack server every single time?

Comment: Are you using Bundler to manage the gems for your app as well? (i.e., do you have a Gemfile for your app?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bundler to manage the gems in your application, you can use Bundler's `path` directive to use a gem that's currently in development.

In your Gemfile:

```
# My awesome gem that I'm developing
gem 'some-awesome-gem', :path => '~/Projects/some_awesome_gem'
```

Essentially, just point the path at the directory where your gem resides and you won't have to package new versions of the gem while you're actively developing it.

See the [Bundler homepage](http://gembundler.com/) and [Gemfile Manual](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html) for more details.